# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{1+11x-6x^2}{(x-3)(1-2x)}$ is a decreasing function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I prove that $f(x)$ is a decrasing function

$$f(x)=\frac{1+11x-6x^2}{(x-3)(1-2x)},x>3$$

---

I did:

$$f{'(x)}=-\frac{4}{(x-3)^2}+\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}$$

$$f^{'}(x)<0$$

then I got

$$-\frac{7}{9}<x<1$$

So where do I go from here

Comment: Your derivative is not correct.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9003

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{1+11x-6x^2}{(x-3)(1-2x)}\\&=\frac{3(-2x^2+7x-3)+11x-21x+1+9}{(x-3)(1-2x)}\\
&=3 + \frac{10(1-x)}{(x-3)(1-2x)}\\
&=3 + \frac{4}{x-3}- \frac{2}{1-2x}\\
&= 3 + \frac4{x-3}+\frac{1}{x-0.5}\end{align}

For $x>3$, as $x$ increases, we can see that $f(x)$ decreases.

Comment: good point. thanks.